# Почему в режиме Debug колонки распределяются неравномерно используя susy?

Tags: css, css3, sass, scss

Почему в режиме Debug колонки распределяются неравномерно используя susy?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я использую GoogleChrome - version 51.0.2704.79 m

Но в  MozilaFireFox - этого не наблюдается.

```
$susy: (
  flow: ltr, 
  math: fluid, 
  output: float, 
  gutter-position: after, 
  container: auto, 
  container-position: center, 
  columns: 12, 
  gutters: .1, 
  column-width: false, 
  global-box-sizing: content-box, 
  last-flow: to, 
  debug: (
    image: show-columns, 
    color: rgba(#ff0000, .60), 
    output: overlay, 
    toggle: top right, 
  ),
  use-custom: ( 
    background-image: true, 
    background-options: false, 
    box-sizing: true, 
    clearfix: false, 
    rem: true,
  )
);


.conteiner{
    margin: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
}

body{
    @include container;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

**html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>None</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/css/modul_setka/susy-min.css">         

        <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    </head>




    <body> 


          test - test 
      test - test 
           test - test 
              <p>test - test </p>  
                     test - test 
                          test - test 
                               test - test 
                                    test - test 
                                         test - test 


    </body>   
</html>
```

Comment: Зачем нам знать вашу секцию head? Приведите лучше разметку самих колонок.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov Так разметку я же привел в глобальных настройках. Или вы имеете  в виду то что находится внутри `body`?  Там что угодно может находится, содержимое контейнера не влияет на эту особенность о которой идет речь. Даже если в контейнер  `body` поместить цифру или любуюу букву, или слова, будет тоже самое.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov Уточните что вы имеете в виду и я это предоставлю.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov Я добавил новые данные в ответ.

Comment: Предоставьте [mcve]. То есть такой пример, который я смогу открыть и увидеть проблему.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov  Я обновил ответ. Как раз до того как вы написали. Посмотрите, я думаю должно хватить данных.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov Опа на, я обнаружил что в ФФ такого нет